# Focusing a vibrating laser source

Tags: laser

I am wondering about the relation between vibrations on the collimated laser source to the change in the focal position, if I focus it using a lens. My system will include a RC telescope to focus the laser, but the overall system can just be considered as a positive lens focusing the source.

Comment: Under which restrictions can we work here? Can we consider the "lens" being thin? Is it important, which distortions to the shape of the focused beam are introduced? Can we consider vibrations always parallel to the focal plane (i.e. there is no change in angle of incidence to the "lens", but only in position)?

Comment: Well, I want to use RC telescope to focus the laser and place the laser on the vibrating table which produces microvirations. So I don't think thin lens assumption will work as it will always focus on the focal point (if I am not mistaken). Considering a f/9 10'' RC telescope, I want to know the proportinality of the motion of the focal spot, if I have 1 microrad vibration